# Firebase Cloud Functions order by child of child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Sorry if my title isn't well formed but I've been trying to do this thing in Cloud Functions:

I've managed to do it in Java like this:

```
 ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    //loop through all UIDs under "Follow" and remove the user ID that deleted his/her account from "followers"
                                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                        if(ds.child("followers").child(uid).exists()){
                                            ds.child("followers").child(uid).getRef().removeValue();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            };
```

This is my current Cloud Function:

```
const followreference = admin.database().ref("Follow");
followreference.orderByChild('followers').equalTo(uid)
.once('value').then((dataSnapshot) => {
  dataSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.remove();
  });
})
```

to my despair, it doesn't work.
Could anyone lead me in the right direction for this?
Thanks

Comment: You're not handling the promise returned by `remove()`.  Your cloud function code must return a promise that  resolves only after all asynchronous work is complete.

Comment: Huh? My full function looks like this https://pastebin.com/SjnaKWGA

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your `index.js` file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ScrYsmJj thank you

Comment: When asked to share your code on Stack Overflow, you are supposed to copy it into the question itself.  Please do not share links to external sites, as those links might not work over time.  Stack Overflow intends to archive this question for everyone to use in the future, and complete code is necessary for that.  Please also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well I didn't want to clutter up the comments either.